# Deleting SObject sharing records with rowcause = implict child

Tags: apex, sharing, manual-sharing

I am totally lost on this, I am trying to delete an opportunity share record using dev console as well as  workbench. I am unable to delete the record with Rowcause = "Implicit Child"

```
List<opportunityshare> oshare = [select id from opportunityshare where OpportunityId=:'006460000032bsR'];
//Trying to delete the first entry.
delete oshare[1];
```

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   00txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, id
>   does not exist: []

We have a custom account team structure and a trigger on this object inserts standard account team which later creates an oppty sharing insert.

Is there a way to delete the record with rowcause='Implicit child'?

[image]

Comment: N.B. same error for `RowCause = Team`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to delete the record with rowcause='Implicit child'?

No. The only share records you are free to insert/update/delete are those with a RowCause of "Manual" and, for custom objects, any RowCause that is a custom type used with Apex Managed Sharing.

Comment: How do i prevent the user from seeing the oppty then :..(

Comment: @Rao You'll need to make sure that whatever is causing the Implicit Child sharing to stop doing that. If I had to guess, I'd say that your code is probably setting OpportunityAccessLevel on the account to a value higher than None.